# Facebook adding tester users and admin is: (pending), what does that mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The new Facebook developer integration should be really handy and easy, but i'm struggling with creating a test user or a regular Facebook user to get permissions to sign in my app.

I opened a "**TestApp**", and login in as a "Admin" works great!
The problem is adding more Facebook accounts and test users.

When i tried to add a Facebook account to "**Testers**" section, i get this (pending) message next to the persons name, and can not log in the app using Facebook with that user!
Same issue with adding a "Admin" to the app:

[image]

After this didn't work, i figured if i create a "TestUser" maybe i'll have better luck, but the test user does not show up when i'm trying to add him to the "Role".

[image]

Any one that can make this clear to me a-bit more will be much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: The user that you are adding in Admin or Tester have to accept the role. They get a notification on facebook.com and when they accept it (pending) disappear.

Comment: That's what i thought! But i do not get any notifications, did you get?

Comment: Why would you get one if you add someone else. The person you add will get it

Comment: Yah its the same thing, its fakeUsers for developing..

Comment: Use test users instead of fake users. Fake users may be deleted at any second and is against policy.

Comment: But that is the the issue, i cannot add test users to the "Testers" section is "Role". And will there are not there, i cannot log in using them

Comment: Testers are real users that you want to be able to test the app. Use Test-users.

Comment: In the image i posted there is a TestUser named "Charlie" that i created. He will not show up at the "Role" when pressing "Add Tester" button. And if he is not there, he has no permissions to log in.

Comment: If he is a test user he doesn't have to be a tester. He will be able to use the app anyway.

Comment: Did it work for you? I tried it with no luck..

Comment: Login with "Charlie" TestUser

Comment: Log in with FaceBook in my app with the TestUser will not work. And if i try to log in with the "Admin", (the original first one, not the pending one), it works.

Comment: @WizKid Thanks for your help! I found what i was doing wrong, the reason users did not receive notifications for a "Tester" was that the notification is received only at the "Developer section of that user. And not at the FaceBook home page.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Found the answer, its a bit silly but if anyone else gets the same issue...

After you add a new user to the "Testers" he gets a notification that he must accept, so the "Pending" will go away, and the user will be activated.

This notification does **not** get to the Facebook home page, only to the "Developer section" of that user. As @rmp251 mentioned, that can be found on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/requests)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't use Fake users. That is against Facebook Policy

Comment: Is this still working with the latest version? I add the fb user to the testers list but it never says pending nor does the fb user get any notification. When going to @Steve url when logged in with the tester user it just tells me I do not have any reqs? What’s going on?

Comment: Very useful answer - seems ridiculous that they state the user will receive a notification without qualifying that it'll **only** appear in the developer area.

Comment: Can we accept the invitation via the Facebook  app?

Comment: Here is the new link: https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/requests/
You have to first "get started" as a developer to see the notification. Ridiculous that you don't even get an email about it.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to add few details on the answer but I cannot comment.

The test user need to register as Facebook developer (if he not reregistered already)

Link: https://developers.facebook.com/async/registration/

After that he need to approve the request from the app

Then he need to approve the request at this link
Link: https://developers.facebook.com/requests/

[image: approve the request]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/requests/ -> Sorry, the link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed.

Comment: This is the new url for developer requests. https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/requests/

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add an administrator to a Page owned by a Gray account.  The invitee would see a notification appear briefly, but it would vanish as soon as they clicked on the Notifications button, and would not show up in their list of notifications.

Workaround: The invitee can go here to see and accept the invite: https://www.facebook.com/pages/?category=invites

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is trying to add Instagram Test Users, there's also no documentation on where this "pending " request goes.

Log into the invited Instagram account in a web browser. Go to https://www.instagram.com/accounts/manage_access/. Click "Test Invites".

Answer (score 0):

Log in from desktop to your instagram tester account. Press MORE then SETTING, then APPS AND WEBSITES and then you'll have a 4th tab TESTER. Also you have to add tester the instagram account that you want to display.