# How to accept facebook tester invitation

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

This exact question has been already asked:
[Facebook adding tester users and admin is: (pending), what does that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625645/facebook-adding-tester-users-and-admin-is-pending-what-does-that-mean)
[Facebook app testers not receiving notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715425/facebook-app-testers-not-receiving-notification)

But answers provided there are no longer valid (https://developers.facebook.com/requests/ no longer works).
The facebook account I have added to 'testers' in developer console is marked as 'pending' and I could not find a way to accept the invitation.
Perhaps someone knows how to do that?

Comment: Rather than create a new question, the appropriate thing would be to create a new answer on the linked page and note that the old answers are not valid because…. As is, this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to login to https://developers.facebook.com/ with the tester account to accept the invitation